# Uso de memoria en C

Tags: c

¿Se puede forzar en C que una variable se almacene en el disco duro, en lugar de la RAM? Y, ¿cómo se podría obtener una lectura de la memoria usada en tiempo real, de manera que un programa se aborte automáticamente si ocupa demasiada? 
 Gracias.

Edito (en respuesta a @gbianchi): el código de re-asignación de memoria es como este:

```
int i;
double x;
double* array;
array=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double));

array[0]=x; //meto el primer valor en el array
for(i=1;i<M;i++)
{
  x=funcion(x); //Obtengo la nueva "x"
  array=realloc(array,sizeof(double)*(i+1)); //Aumento el tamaño del 
                                       //array...
  array[i]=x; //... Y guardo el nuevo valor
}
```

Comment: Existen técnicas dependientes del sistema operativo como [`mmap`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html) que te permiten acceder a archivos como si fueran zonas de memoria normales, pero al final siempre estará pasando la información por la memoria. Si quieres persistencia deberás guardar la información en un archivo y SIEMPRE pasarás en algún momento por un almacenamiento temporal (buffer) en memoria que no podrás saltarte. En cuanto al uso de memoria, le doy mi +1 a @Paula_plus_plus por indicarte lo mismo que yo, que depende del sistema operativo.

Comment: Al hilo de lo que estás comentando en la respuesta facilitada por @Paula_plus_plus, ¿qué estás haciendo y qué te genera esa necesidad? Quizá estés optando por una solución que no es óptima para el problema. Por ejemplo, hablaste de "un array de doubles (64 B) de 2^30 elementos = 68 gigas". Eso puede solucionarse fácilmente con `mmap` y la solución que te dije que adopta Windows, pero quizá haya una forma de manejar tal cantidad de elementos de una manera mejor en la que no todos deban estar al mismo tiempo en memoria o disco (por poner un ejemplo).

Comment: @OscarGarcia por ahí iban mis intentos de optimización, pero no lo veo realmente fácil... Mi programa genera números mediante una función x(n+1)=f[x(n)], guarda cada número (por eso el array enorme), y compara cada nuevo número generado con todos los anteriores (y el programa acaba si hay una coincidencia). Tiene que guardar como máximo 2^N números. Toda la optimización que he logrado en cuanto a memoria es re-asignar la memoria del array dinámicamente con cada nuevo número (en lugar de guardar desde el principio ese "array enorme")

Comment: Reasignar memoria me hizo dar miedo. Decime que no copias el array a cada rato si no que tenes alguna especie de lista donde vas agregando las items que necesitas. Algo de lo que estas queriendo hacer no me cierra (y ya es agnostico del lenguaje)

Comment: No necesitas 2^N elementos para guardar un histórico de resultados. A lo sumo serían N elementos. ¿Me equivoco? ¿En qué sistema operativo estás desarrollando la aplicación? Si es Unix/Linux podría darte instrucciones del sistema y  código C para lo que preguntas, y si compartes más información de la función que estás calculando podríamos darte una manera más óptima de solucionarla o reducirla.

Comment: La notación 2^N es confusa. No hay "N" elementos, si no 2^N elementos (ese "N" simplemente es un parámetro arbitrario del programa). La función es un mapa logístico: x(n+1)=a*x(n)*[1-x(n)], donde a es un número real. La cantidad "x", aunque definida double, solo puede tomar una serie de 2^N valores, donde "N" se introduce como "input" al inicio del programa. La idea es que el programa salte cuando se repite alguno de los 2^N posibles valores de x

Comment: No deberias estar usando algun tipo de estructura tipo arbol, o algo que crezca a medida que lo vas necesitando, pero que ademas permita optimizar las busquedas de lo que estas generando? ademas del problema de espacio, no hay como un problema de velocidad? si usaras un arbol o algo asi, swappear seria mas facil, hasta lo podrias hacer vos mismo.

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces un `malloc` del tamaño total la primera vez ya que conoces de antemano el tamaño final? Un `realloc` puede forzar una copia de datos si tiene que alojarse la memoria en una nueva piscina o reserva de espacio de memoria lineal solicitada al sistema operativo o por motivos de superposición o fragmentación de memoria, ocupando durante ese momento el doble de memoria (el tamaño anterior más el nuevo). Además, el tamaño final será `sizeof(double)*M`, y no 2^M.

Comment: @OscarGarcia esa era la implementación original del programa; introduje la modificación del realloc porque necesitaba guardar tamaños (máximos) del orden de M=2^40 --> Se sale de la RAM

Comment: No entiendo por qué necesitaste hacer esa modificación, no aporta nada exceptuando fragmentación de memoria. En cuanto al sistema operativo, si me dices en cuál estás desarrollando puedo decirte cómo implementar `mmap` para alojar toda esa memoria directamente en disco en vez de en RAM.

Comment: Uso Ubuntu; esa modificación es para evitar guardar un array gigantesco en la memoria: si NO uso realloc, tengo que guardar un array del orden de 2^40 elementos. En cambio, utilizando realloc,  necesito guardar arrays de aproximadamente 500.000 elementos

Comment: Entiendo, con realloc lo que haces es ir reservando memoria conforme no encuentras la coincidencia ya que es probable que no sea necesario reservarla para todas las opciones. ¿Quieres hacerlo en C puro o te puedo agregar C++? (con C++ puedo usar boost para simplificar el código de mmap). Entra en este chat: [https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73181/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-guillermo-d-s](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73181/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-guillermo-d-s)

Comment: Tras la toma de datos realizada en los comentarios he procedido a redactar una respuesta. Espero que sea de tu agrado y pueda solucionarte el problema que sufres con tu programa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ¿Se puede forzar en C que una variable se almacene en el disco duro, en lugar de la RAM?

No. El almacenamiento en memoria RAM y disco duro son cosas distintas. Como analogía, la RAM sería un panel de luces y el disco duro sería grabar letras en piedra:

[image]
[image]

La RAM es rápida y tiene una comunicación más directa con el sistema mientras que la piedra es lenta y su comunicación con el sistema es más lenta y tediosa.

Puedes escribir datos en disco duro desde una variable o recuperar datos desde el disco duro y escribirlos en una variable.

> ¿Cómo se podría obtener una lectura de la memoria usada en tiempo real, de manera que un programa se aborte automáticamente si ocupa demasiada?

El sistema operativo es el gestor de la memoria del sistema, si quieres conocer la memoria gastada por un proceso deberás comunicarte con el sistema operativo, cada sistema operativo pone a disposición del programador librerías o utilidades para este fin, pero éstas varían por cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73195/discussion-on-answer-by-paula-plus-plus-uso-de-memoria-en-c).

Answer (score 6):

### Preguntas iniciales

Voy a responderte con los datos aportados en los comentarios a la espera de que modifiques la pregunta en base a ellos.

#### ¿Se puede forzar en C que una variable se almacene en el disco duro, en lugar de la RAM?

Las variables SIEMPRE se almacenan en la memoria del ordenador y no es posible realizar lo que preguntas tal y como lo planteas.

Ahora bien, atendiendo a los datos adicionales que aportas en los comentarios, es posible mapear el contenido de un archivo en memoria. El sistema operativo gestionará los cambios de página entre memoria y el archivo de manera transparente al programador.

#### ¿cómo se podría obtener una lectura de la memoria usada en tiempo real, de manera que un programa se aborte automáticamente si ocupa demasiada?

El lenguaje de programación C no provee mecanismos para consultar el uso de memoria de una aplicación.

Ahora bien, atendiendo a los datos adicionales proporcionados en los comentarios, tienes dos soluciones posibles.

---

### Respuestas específicas

Teniendo en cuenta la naturaleza de tu código (deseas hacer uso de una zona de memoria que va creciendo con el paso del tiempo) y la plataforma en la que lo ejecutas (Ubuntu), las soluciones que te propongo (junto con una leve modificación a las preguntas para que estén más acordes a tu problema) son las siguientes:

#### ¿Se puede mapear en C el contenido de un archivo para usarlo en mi aplicación como si fuera parte de la memoria?

Sí. Prácticamente todos los sistemas operativos actuales soportan mapeo de archivos en memoria. Es una técnica similar a la memoria virtual, en la que el sistema operativo gestiona los fallos de página para traer zonas del archivo a la memoria y volcarlas de nuevo al archivo con cada modificación de manera transparente.

En sistemas operativos POSIX se usa [`mmap`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html):

> Since mmapped pages can be stored back to their file when physical memory is low, it is possible to mmap files orders of magnitude larger than both the physical memory and swap space. The only limit is address space.

La traducción:

> Como las páginas mapeadas en memoria pueden ser almacenadas de vuelta en su archivo cuando la memoria física es baja, es posible mapear en memoria archivos de órdenes de magnitud superior que la memoria física y de intercambio juntas. El único límite es el espacio de direccionamiento.

En Windows puedes consultar: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx

Un ejemplo muy sencillo de uso de `mmap` lo tienes en el [siguiente gist](https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/b7cf58c74fec203c390fd096fe2ec277):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    double *datos;
    int fd;
    size_t filesize;
    /* Si no indicamos el archivo a usar, fallamos la ejecución */
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Uso: %s <archivo>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    /* Tratamos de crear el archivo nuevo */
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU);
    /* Si falla la creación tratamos de abrirlo */
    if (fd == -1) {
        struct stat st;
        /* Abrimos el archivo previo */
        fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
        assert(fd != -1);
    }
    /* Reservamos la memoria que deseemos, es el equivalente al "malloc" */
    filesize = 12000 * sizeof(double);
    /* Creamos el archivo al tamaño deseado */
    ftruncate(fd, filesize);
    /* Mapeamos el contenido del archivo en memoria */
    datos = (double *)mmap(NULL, filesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE, fd, 0);
    assert(datos != MAP_FAILED);
    /* Leemos el valor inicial y lo modificamos */
    printf("Datos iniciales: %lf\n", datos[0]);
    datos[0] = 3.141592;
    /* Desmapeamos el archivo de la memoria */
    int rc = munmap(datos, filesize);
    assert(rc == 0);
    /* Cerramos el archivo */
    close(fd);
}
```

Un ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
$ ./ejemplo /tmp/ejemplo
Datos iniciales: 0.000000
$ ./ejemplo /tmp/ejemplo
Datos iniciales: 3.141592
$ ls -ltrh /tmp/ejemplo
-rwx------ 1 ... 94K ... /tmp/ejemplo
$ du -hs /tmp/ejemplo
4,0K    /tmp/ejemplo
```

Donde puedes ver que se hace uso de [archivos dispersos (sparse files)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_disperso) para almacenar la información. Sólo las áreas de memoria con valores diferentes de `0`s ocupan espacio en disco. En este ejemplo se hace uso de 4K en disco (el tamaño mínimo de un archivo) aunque se muestre 94K como tamaño del mismo.

Ese código no funcionará en Windows, por lo que te he dejado un ejemplo portable haciendo uso de `boost` en el [este gist](https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/161a8dd38bc8510fc7afd299ce223313).

#### ¿Cómo podría limitar el uso de memoria o bien obteniendo el uso para controlarlo o bien de otra manera?

En sistemas operativos POSIX tienes disponible [`getrusage()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) (ver ejemplo más adelante).

Pero, más interesante aún, tu sistema operativo te permite limitar los recursos usados a través de la herramienta de la shell del sistema [`ulimit`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit) o bien a través de la función C [`setrlimit()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit).

Usando `limit` podríamos limitar el uso de memoria de lo que ejecutemos de este momento en adelante en esa consola (si cambiamos a otra no se habrá alterado y si creamos una nueva el límite se restablecerá) de la siguiente manera:

```
$ ulimit -v $((100*1024))
```

De esta manera limitaremos el uso a 100 MB de memoria de ese momento en adelante (hasta cerrar ese terminal y sólo lo que se ejecute dentro de él).

A través de `setrlimit` necesitarás asignar `RLIMIT_AS`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void *mem1, *mem2;
    struct rusage uso;
    struct rlimit limite;
    /* Limitamos la memoria a 100 MB */
    limite.rlim_cur = limite.rlim_max = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
    setrlimit (RLIMIT_AS, &limite);
    /* Pedir 10 KB será posible */
    mem1 = malloc(10 * 1024);
    printf("Memoria 1: %p\n", mem1);
    /* Pedir 100 MB adicionales ya no será posible */
    mem2 = malloc(100 * 1024 * 1024);
    printf("Memoria 2: %p\n", mem2);
    /* Mostrará el uso de memoria (sólo la primera reserva más pila) */
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &uso);
    printf("Uso de memoria: %ld KB\n", (long)uso.ru_maxrss);
}
```

El resultado de la ejecución sería:

```
$ ./ejemplo 
Memoria 1: 0x899010
Memoria 2: (nil)
Uso de memoria: 4988 KB
```

Falló la segunda petición de memoria debido a haber excedido los límites impuestos.

El contenido de [`ru_maxrss`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) está en KB:

> **`ru_maxrss`** This is the maximum resident set size used (in kilobytes).